# Can't Write to SQLite Database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my app, I have a SQLite database to store information. When starting my main activity, I initialize the database. This the onCreate code for the database:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_OWES + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_VALUE + " INTEGER" + ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

I have a button and two editText fields to send information to the database and add it. The code in the activity which triggers on the button press:

```
 public void addAnOwe(View v){
    EditText description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionAdd);
    EditText value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueAdd);
    Owe newOwe = new Owe(description.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString()));
    DB.addOwe(newOwe);
    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to add Owe");

    updateLists();
}
public void updateLists(){
    descriptionList = DB.DBtoArray("desc");
    valueList = DB.DBtoArray("value");
    oweAdapter.updateValues(valueList);
    oweAdapter.updateDescriptions(descriptionList);
    updateTotalViewText();
}
```

The code in the DBManager:

```
public void addOwe(Owe owe){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String description = owe.get_desc();
    String value = String.valueOf(owe.get_value());

    values.put(COLUMN_DESC, description);
    values.put(COLUMN_VALUE, value);

    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to add: " + description + " - " + value);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_OWES, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

At this point all of the log messages are showing the the DBManager is receiving both the description and the value correctly. However there are two methods I use to read information from the database. The first one, I wrote myself:

```
public String[] DBtoArray(String column){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_OWES + " WHERE 1", null);
    String[] array = new String[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        array[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(column));
        i++;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "String of db is " + databaseToString());
    Log.i(TAG, "Array Log is " + Arrays.toString(array));
    return array;
}
```

The second one is called in the method databaseToString(), which I copied from elsewhere in case my method was written incorrectly.

```
 public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_OWES + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESC)) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESC));
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

The loggers in DBtoArray both show that the database is empty. The methods are being called one after the other as can be seen in the addAnOwe() method. Why isn't the data being saved?

Comment: Are you extending SQLiteOpenHelper in your database class?  Everything looks good from what I can see initially.

Comment: Yes, I'm extending all of the requisite classes and there's no errors in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply pass DB.addOwe(String description, Integer x) and accept likely in the DBHelper class!?  You're storing a string and an integer but you want to put them into another object which you intend to retrieve in DBHelper to get back the values of the parameters inside the object using another method.  I believe that passing values directly Reduces lot of complexity and runtime. :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll definitely implement it, but unfortunately it won't matter unless I can figure out how to write to the database.